Does Stock Windows IThumbnailProvider Permit QueryInterface For IInitializeWithStream For Video Files?
Microsoft writes regarding IThumbnailProvider:

The object that implements this interface must also implement IInitializeWithStream.

In fact, they mention several times on MSDN that anyone implementing IThumbnailProvidershould permit it to be initialized with IInitializeWithStream.
After reading this question and seeing the table produced by – @[Denis Anisimov] that shows a surprising number of file extensions whose IThumbnailProvider's do not support IInitializeWithStream, I wrote the following test code to see what Windows does for .wmv files. It appears that the stock Windows IThumbnailProvider does not support IInitializeWithStream for many video file extensions. Is this true? It apparently does support IInitializeWithItem, but I much prefer IInitializeWithStream.
int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    TCHAR guid_of_handler_as_string[64];
    DWORD dwCount = ARRAYSIZE(guid_of_handler_as_string);

    HRESULT hr = AssocQueryString(
        ASSOCF_NONE,
        ASSOCSTR_SHELLEXTENSION,
        TEXT(".wmv"),
        TEXT("{e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96}"), // GUID of IThumbnailProvider
        guid_of_handler_as_string, // ... becomes {9DBD2C50-62AD-11D0-B806-00C04FD706EC}.
        &dwCount);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        GUID guid_of_handler;

        hr = IIDFromString(String(guid_of_handler_as_string).dump<OLECHAR>(), &guid_of_handler);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            IThumbnailProvider *pThumbnailProvider = 0;

            hr = CoCreateInstance(guid_of_handler, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pThumbnailProvider));

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IInitializeWithStream *pInitializeWithStream = 0;
                IInitializeWithItem *pInitializeWithItem = 0;
                IInitializeWithFile *pInitializeWithFile = 0;

                hr = pThumbnailProvider->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pInitializeWithStream)); // ... becomes E_NOINTERFACE.

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    int i = 0; // We never arrive here.

                    pInitializeWithStream->Release();
                }

                pThumbnailProvider->Release();
            }
        }
    }

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}

UPDATE:
As @Simon Mourier noted, responding with a valid IStream * for IPropertyStore::GetValue against PKEY_ThumbnailStream works better. With this method, I can see calls to my IStream::read, IStream::seek and IStream::stat. The amount of data read never exceeds 88 bytes in a single IStream::read and total number of bytes read in an IStream is < 250, so something is clearly wrong. My IStream is created twice, which make sense, as the Shell renders twice for the same thumbnail (I think). But the thumbnail is never rendered. I checked the call sequence and discovered that GdiPlus.dll!GpBitmap::IsValid
is returning false after finishing extracting data from the IStream and closing it:
000007FEF73506A4  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx  
000007FEF73506A9  push        rdi  
000007FEF73506AA  sub         rsp,20h  
000007FEF73506AE  xor         ebx,ebx  
000007FEF73506B0  mov         rdi,rcx  
000007FEF73506B3  cmp         qword ptr [rcx+20h],rbx  
000007FEF73506B7  je          GpBitmap::IsValid+31h (07FEF73506D5h)  
000007FEF73506B9  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx+20h]  
000007FEF73506BD  mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  
000007FEF73506C0  call        qword ptr [rax+10h]  
000007FEF73506C3  cmp         eax,ebx  
000007FEF73506C5  je          GpBitmap::IsValid+31h (07FEF73506D5h)  
000007FEF73506C7  cmp         dword ptr [rdi+8],676D4931h  
000007FEF73506CE  jne         GpBitmap::IsValid+31h (07FEF73506D5h)  
000007FEF73506D0  mov         ebx,1  
000007FEF73506D5  mov         eax,ebx  
000007FEF73506D7  mov         rbx,qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
000007FEF73506DC  add         rsp,20h  
000007FEF73506E0  pop         rdi  
000007FEF73506E1  ret

I then checked my IStream class carefully and did not find any errors. Finally, I used SHCreateStreamOnFile to create an IStream against wildlife.wmv in the file system:
    PropVariantInit(pv);

    pv->vt = VT_STREAM;

    auto hr = SHCreateStreamOnFile(
    TEXT("C:\\Users\\Karl\\Desktop\\Bucket\\wildlife.wmv"),
        STGM_READWRITE | STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE,
        &pv->pStream
    );

    return hr;

SHCreateStreamOnFile returned S_OK, but again, the thumbnail is never rendered.

Well why don't you just try? Call QueryInterface and inspect its return value. If it returns E_NOINTERFACE then no.  Side notes, use ::CoInitializeEx, And use ATL::CComPtr for your com interface pointers. That way you don't have to manually make sure your Addref/Releases add up.

I did try with the code above, and got E_NOINTERFACE, . Given that Microsoft strongly recommended that IStream be supported by all IThumbnailProvider's, I was hoping that I missed something. [Thanks for tips.]

Well at least you got the sensible HRESULT, even if it isn't the one you would like seeing.
About CComPtr, useful link here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/how-to-create-and-use-ccomptr-and-ccomqiptr-instances?view=msvc-170

Although the documentation states something, you should never assume what a COM object implements. But IInitializeWithItem is generally more powerful than all others, why do you absolutely need IInitializeWithStream?

WMV is a video format.  Beyond the need for a codec to read them, video streams are not a great source for still images.  Too many to choose from.

@SimonMourier IInitializeWithItem would be fine, which did work. I used SHCreateItemFromIDList to make the IShellItem, used it to initialize the ~IThumbnailProvider~, and waited to see what callbacks would be made into my NSE to get the data. I only looked briefly, but did not see anything significant. I will check my PIDL's and try again with IInitializeWithItem.

If you're working in a namespace extension, the IShellFolder implementation can be called for IThumbnailHandlerFactory which you should implement. For each item you can be asked for IExtractIcon, IExtractImage (more for legacy), and IThumbnailProvider, or even IStream if the file extension is known and some providers require it. Also make sure your item's IPropertyStore has PKEY_ThumbnailCacheId it's very important for thumbnail caching/performance.

I've done all of those things except putting IStream directly in IThumbnailProvider.  Thumbnails work for IInitializeWithStream. I need to figure-out what call sequence will be used for IInitializeWithItem. When I gave a IThumbnailProvider' using IInitializeWithItem, no thumbnail appeared, and I did not see any calls back into my NSE asking for IStreamanywhere. Indeed, Microsoft's approach toPKEY_ThumbnailCacheIdandPKEY_DateModified` is very nice and solves a lot of would-be performance problems.

Difficult to say w/o code but your NSE's should implement an IPropertyStore for all items, and the store should contain PKEY_Thumbnail or PKEY_ThumbnailStream.

Added new information to my question. [Do I have to notify when I add new notes?]
